# If the Milky Way contained a Quasar

Tags: alternate-history, astronomy

If the central Milky Way contained a highly active, accreting quasar, with a steady luminosity of 100 trillion solar that is 27,000 lightyears away and became active 27,000 years ago (the emissions would only begin reaching us more-or-less now):

1) Would this affect human biology?

2) Would this affect our day/night cycle?

3) Would the emissive radiation affect our technology?

Comment: If the quasar just switched on from Earth’s point of view, life would definitely develop as normal before then because nothing exceeds the speed of light. There wouldn’t be any anomalous light or particles before then.

Comment: Uhm, you can already read fine under starlight. even better moonlight.

Comment: VTCers... The OP can't improve his question without insight into your complaint (which I disagree with).  Why is this off-topic due to our rules?  Which rule?  The only problem I have with this question is that, asking 3 questions rather than just one, it might be too broad.

Comment: My VTC was because there's no worldbuilding aspect to this.  It's (yet another) what-if science question.  No worldbuilding, so off-topic.

Answer (score 7):

27,000 light years is 1,707,509,000 AU. By the inverse square law, something at that distance is less than one pentillionth as bright as if it was at the same distance as the sun. So something with a luminosity of 100 trillion solar would be less than one ten thousandth as bright as the sun. That’s brighter than a full moon, so you could just about read by it, if the light wasn’t blocked by dust between here and the centre of the galaxy, which it probably would be.

Comment: However the dust clouds would likely heat up, so there might be a flood of infrared radiation or even a red glow in the direction of the centre of the galaxy. The powerful jets of the quasar might provide some illumination as they clear the plane of the galaxy as well.

Answer (score 3):

I beg to differ from Mike.

There is a quasar that has a luminosity of 140 trillion suns, so it is around the same order of magnitude as yours. It is called TON 618.

From [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TON_618):

> The surrounding galaxy is not visible from Earth, because the quasar itself outshines it.

Part of what makes a body luminous is how large it is. That's because black bodies of the same material and at the same temperature emit the same amount of radiation per area, so more area = more light. If the quasar in question was just as big as the sun, it just might be as bright as our galactic center. But TON 618 is big:

> (...) the mass of the black hole in TON 618 is 66 billion solar masses.

For a black hole of such mass, the [general article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) suggests a radius of 400 AU. The accretion disc, which is the part that gives out EM radiation, would be far larger than that.

For comparison, the black hole at our galactic center has a radius of less than a sixth of an AU.

In other words, the quasar you mention would be disproportionally big, and disproportionally brighter than our galactic center. It's accretion disc would outshine the rest of the galaxy.

In fact, there would be so much radiation coming out of it that ice cores would never form in the galaxy. Without these, gas and ice giants would not form. This is bad for us because planets like Jupiter are thought to greatly reduce bombardment of asteroids and comets on smaller planets, by clearing the system of any bodies with highly excentric orbits over time. Even if that were not a problem, any rocky planets wouldn't be able to hold atmospheres. Any life arising in such a galaxy would develop on molten rock while exposed to hard vacuum and amounts of radiation that are comparable to a [neverending supernova](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/25675/31264).

Comment: `Part of what makes a body luminous is how large it is`.  Can you explain this or provide a source?

Comment: @cowlinator I edited my answer to elaborate on that.

Comment: Luminosity indicates the apparent brightness of a star as a whole taking size into consideration.  So, making a fixed luminosity quasar bigger or smaller does not make it brighter, you just adjust the other factors to match the luminosity.